# How to open multiple folders in a specific order using batch file? Windows 10

Tags: windows, batch-file

Currently I use the below script but it doesn't open the folders in the given order. It opens the folders in a random order.

```
@echo off
start explorer "Folder 1 Path"
start explorer "Folder 2 Path"
start explorer "Folder 3 Path"
start explorer "Folder 4 Path"
```

Comment: Insert some delay (1-2s) between the commands. For example...

Comment: You can use `timeout` command in middle of every command. Use `timeout /t 2`, if you want `timeout` to stay quiet, `timeout /t 2 >nul`. It should work

Comment: @Akina How do I add time delays?

Comment: @Jhon I added that. But not working. Where do I add "timeout /t 2" exactly?

Comment: You must add a command provided by @Jhon between each pair of your `start` commands. PS. Really you do not need in `start`, you may execute `explorer "Folder N Path"` only.

Comment: @Akina Worked. Thanks!!!

Comment: @Jhon Post your comment as answer!!! I will mark that as the answer.

Comment: @RvidD Sure, I will

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `timeout` command in middle of every command. Use `timeout /t 2`, if you want timeout to stay quiet, `timeout /t 2 >nul`. It should work. Just make your code like this:

```
@echo off
start explorer "Folder 1 Path"
timeout /t 2 >nul
start explorer "Folder 2 Path"
timeout /t 2 >nul
start explorer "Folder 3 Path"
timeout /t 2 >nul
start explorer "Folder 4 Path"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Using a `for` loop listing in order would be...

```
@echo off

for %%i in (
     "%UserProfile%\Desktop"
     "%UserProfile%\Documents"
     "%UserProfile%\Downloads"
     "%UserProfile%\Pictures"
    )do start "" "%%~i"
```

Answer (score 1):

Chain it together on one line.

```
start "" "folder1"|start "" "folder2"|start "" "folder3"
```

Comment: When seeing this answer, I thought it will work. But it opens the folders in random order :(

Answer (score 0):

This is the .bat file content:

```
for /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%A in ("dirs.txt") do explorer %%A
```

- You need to create the file dirs.txt which contains the full path of the directories respectively

This is an example of "dirs.txt" file content:

```
C:\Users\User\Desktop\1
C:\Users\User\Desktop\2
C:\Users\User\Desktop\3
C:\Users\User\Desktop\New Folder
```

**Edit1:**

**usebackq** is used to handle folders with white spaces.

Comment: Unfortunately, as-is, this suffers from the same issue that OP is trying to resolve. You could add the necessary timeouts into the loop, of course.